# Adblock Plus hiding social media links below questions on SO

Tags: support

Adblock Plus for Chrome was updated today. It has an option to prevent social media tracking via icons 
[image: adblock plus settings page]

Enabling it has caused the bottom-notice below a question to have missing text where `Google+`, `Twitter` and `Facebook` used to be
[image]

---

I am guessing a large number of SO users will have some sort of ad-blocking software installed in their systems and this is what they will be seeing now. Maybe the message can be changed to not look so strange when it happens?

Comment: Is it reasonable to ask a company to make sure their site still looks nice when you block their source of income? I know they've said they'd rather have fewer people who will never click on ads seeing them (it helps campaign numbers) but this might be a bridge too far.

Comment: I hear you. I have enabled ads on SO myself on my personal Chrome profile. I have a work profile in Chrome with all ads disabled and I am guessing a lot of people will have their ads blocked everywhere. This is is no way a demand from me. Simply a suggestion.

Comment: @BSMP Do not confuse ads with social media tracking. The former generates income, the latter does not.

Comment: *Do not confuse ads with social media tracking.* @Stijn I didn't. The social media icons are getting blocked *because* they're using an ad blocker. If you're blocking the social media tracking then you're also blocking the ads (whitelisting the site causes it to also ignore the block social media tracking rule).

Comment: @BSMP That depends on the rulesets you have active. It's perfectly possible to only block social media tracking while still allowing ads.

Comment: @BSMP given the current general mood, disabling social media tracking is something I see a lot of people will be opting in for. As I have said in another comment, that number could be a non-trivial % of users for SO

Comment: I wasn't suggesting people wouldn't. Just trying (and failing apparently) to explain that I know the difference between social links and actual ads.

Comment: You are right to some extent with regards to the ad blocking + social media tracking. Whitelisting a site will also ignore social media tracking rule. But StackOverflow ads are *Acceptable* for ABP. If I allow acceptable ads and disable social media tracking, I continue to see ads here and not see the social media links in question

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, those are just plain links, no special attributes, no special CSS, no backgrounds, no images at all. The only thing different between them and the other links on that line is they go to social media sites. Why would AdBlock Plus even block those?

Answer (score 7):

Anyone running extensions to block parts of a website should expect quirks here and there. I've been blocking social media tracking for years via other extensions (Ghostery, uBlock Origin) and got used to it very quickly.

You cannot expect websites to allocate resources for something that ultimately does not matter at all.

Comment: For any other website, sure, it might not matter a lot. For a website that caters to an audience of developers it could be a non trivial % of total audience. Whether or not this matters is something I cannot say. I just thought that this should be highlighted :)

Comment: @Sinstein Would it be easy to code? Probably. But you have to consider that the code necessary to do it adds a small amount of bytes to the total JS, which every single user has to download. Adding a code fix for this, to accommodate a portion of users which intentionally delete things from the page is simply not worth the performance hit, however small the code change is.